# how do i make text in nav bar not stack on eachothet?

Tags: html, css

I want to put the text "Portfolio-updates" in one line.
[image: webpage]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(251, 255, 216);
}

.header {
  width: 1920px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.nav {
  width: 1920px;
  background-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  color: white;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rutger Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519681393784-d120267933ba?w=1920" width="1920">
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Over mij</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projecten</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio-updates</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Archief</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

i tried text-align center, and searching on internet but i don't really know what to search.
It's probbably a simple thing that i just overlook but if someone can take 1 min of there day to help me i would appricate it. (also english is not my native langue so sorry for any spelling mistakes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi i saw your code and i try it and its the result :

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  background-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Center the items horizontally */
}

    enter code here

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

i changed this things :
I made a few changes to your CSS code to achieve the desired result:

Removed the fixed width on .nav: Previously, you had set a fixed width of 1920px for the .nav container. I removed this fixed width to make the navigation bar responsive to different screen sizes.

Added justify-content: center; to ul: By adding this CSS property to the ul element,

it horizontally centers the list items within the .nav container. This ensures that

all list items stay on the same line and are centered, regardless of the screen width.

These changes should help you achieve a navigation bar where all list items remain in a single line and are centered horizontally.

i hope i could aid you
happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

add this code in you css
or add width here

```
ul li a{
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*width:150px*/ //if needed
}
```

Your CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(251, 255, 216);
}

.header {
  width: 1920px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.nav {
  width: 1920px;
  background-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  color: white;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

your HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rutger Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519681393784-d120267933ba?w=1920" width="1920">
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Over mij</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projecten</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio-updates</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Archief</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of your code.

Instead of `width: 1920px;` on `.nav`, use `max-width: 1920px; width: 100%;` instead. This way, your design stays responsive on bigger screens, but limits the amount of space the navbar may use.

`ul` has two display properties, `flex` and `inline-block`. Removed `flex`, since you're not using it.

If you don't want your element to break at hyphens, you can use `‑` a NON-BREAKING HYPHEN (U+2011) (HTML: `&#x2011;` or `&#8209;`), or add `white-space: nowrap;`. I did the second option, as it's cleaner and easier to read and edit.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(251, 255, 216);
}

.header {
  width: 1920px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.nav {
  max-width: 1920px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  color: white;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rutger Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519681393784-d120267933ba?w=1920" width="1920">
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Over mij</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projecten</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio-updates</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Archief</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```